# Why does AWS Amplify try to authenticate with CUSTOM_AUTH when I have chosen USER_SRP_AUTH as the authentication flow type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-cdk, amplifyjs

I have a web application hosted on AWS S3, which allows users to authenticate using AWS Cognito.

The user pool is configured in AWS CDK (1.70.0) using the following:

```
const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, "user-pool", {
    enableSmsRole: false,
    mfa: cognito.Mfa.OFF,
    signInAliases: {
      email: true
    },
    standardAttributes: {
      email: { mutable: true, required: true }
    },
    userPoolName: "user-pool"
  });

  const client = userPool.addClient("user-pool-client", {
    preventUserExistenceErrors: true,
    authFlows: {
      userSrp: true
    },
    oAuth: {
      flows: {
        implicitCodeGrant: true,
      },
      scopes: [cognito.OAuthScope.OPENID, cognito.OAuthScope.EMAIL]
    }
  });
```

AWS Amplify is configured with the following:

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        authenticationFlowType: 'USER_SRP_AUTH',
        mandatorySignIn: true,
        region: "eu-west-1",
        userPoolId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        userPoolWebClientId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        oauth: {
            domain: "somedomain.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com",
            redirectSignIn: ["https://abc123.cloudfront.net", "localhost:8080"],
            redirectSignOut: "",
            responseType: "token",
            scope: ["email"]
        },
    },
});
```

Yet when I try to log in using `Auth.signIn(email, password);`, the request payload sent to cognito-idp is

```
{
    "AuthFlow":"CUSTOM_AUTH",
    "ClientId":"XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "AuthParameters":{"USERNAME":"user@test.com"},
    "ClientMetadata":{}
}
```

And I receive the error `CUSTOM_AUTH is not enabled for the client`.

Is there some configuration I'm missing? I'm very confused as to why Amplify is trying to use CUSTOM_AUTH even though I have explicitly stated USER_SRP_AUTH in the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved.**

The answer was as simple as, use `Auth.federatedSignIn()` instead of `Auth.signIn()`. Not particularly clear error messages *or* documentation. Will leave this here in case anyone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

To me this happened because I forget to set the password.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4915#issuecomment-599812751